# Is it possible to transpose exactly 1 selected row columns into rows

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, oracle-sqldeveloper, transpose

As title says, is it possible to transpose exactly one selected row from tables into columns? I am using Oracle databases. For example i have a bit complex query:

```
SELECT t1.id,
  t1.data1,
  t1.data2,
  t2.data1,
  t2.data2,
  t2.data3,
  subs1.data1,
  subs2.data1,
  subs2.data2
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
JOIN
  (SELECT st1.id,
    st1.data1
  FROM subTable1 st1
  JOIN subTable2
  ON st1.id             = st2.id
  WHERE st2.data1       > 1
  ) AS subs1 ON subs.id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT st3.id,
    st4.data1,
    st4.data2
  FROM subTable3 st3
  JOIN subTable4 st4
  ON st3.id = st4.id
  UNION
  SELECT st4.id, st4.data1, st4.data2 FROM subTable4 st4 WHERE st4.data1 = 1
  ) AS subs2.id = t1.id
WHERE t1.id     = 1
```

Result of the query should be following and always will be exactly one row:

```
+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| t1.id  |  t1.data1   |  t1.data2   |   t2data1   |  t2.data2   |  t2.data3   |  subs1.data1   |  subs2.data1   |  subs2.data2   |
+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| someId | someT1Data1 | someT1Data2 | someT2Data1 | someT2Data2 | someT2Data3 | someSubs1Data1 | someSubs2Data1 | someSubs2Data2 |
+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

What am I willing to achieve should look like this:

```
+-------------+----------------+
|    col1     |      col2      |
+-------------+----------------+
| t1.id       | someId         |
| t1.data1    | someT1Data1    |
| t1.data2    | someT1Data2    |
| t2data1     | someT2Data1    |
| t2.data2    | someT2Data2    |
| t2.data3    | someT2Data3    |
| subs1.data1 | someSubs1Data1 |
| subs2.data1 | someSubs2Data1 |
| subs2.data2 | someSubs2Data2 |
+-------------+----------------+
```

NOTE: col1 is not necessary in output

So the question is:
Is there some easy workaround to transpose exactly one selected row from tables into columns? I mean some easier way than use of PIVOT() function or if there is not other alternative, how to use PIVOT() on a bit complicated query (nested queries etc.)?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pivot` is the tool for the job, but you can also achieve the same result by placing your query in a `CTE` and then using multiple `union all` to get the columns separately:

```
with cte as (
    /* your query, with appropriate aliases for columns with same name*/
)
select 't1.id' as col1, cte.id as col2 from cte union all
select 't1.data1', cte.data1 from cte union all
...
select 'subs2.data2', cte.subsdata2 from cte
```

Answer (score 1):

**Pivot** will be a better option in this case. Just use this query after you achieve first part of the result.

```
SELECT col1, col2 from @Table
 Unpivot
(Col2 For Col1 IN 
(t1.id,t1.data1,t1.data2,t2.data1,t2.data2,t2.data3,subs1.data1,subs2.data1,subs2.data2)) AS a
```

Let me know in case you face any difficulty.

Comment: @Barkezy if the answer helped you, kindly accept and UV.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Should I replace @Table with my example SELECTion to make it work?